# In Python, how to get indices of lists of lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Input:

List of lists : x[x2[x1]]

A 1-D representation of input x[x2[x1]]

```
matrix = [['.', '+', '.', '.', '-'], 
          ['.', '+', '.', '-', '-'], 
          ['.', '+', '.', '.', '-'], 
          ['.', '+', '.', '.', '-']]
```

A 2-D representation of input x[x2[x1]] (NOTE: This is not the required output)

```
x1-> 0 1 2 3 4   
  0  . + . . -
  1  . + . - - 
  2  . + . . -
  3  . + . . -
 x2^
```

## Expected Output:

- "Raster" ordering of instances of '+'s and '-'s
- Output format :
  (x1,x2,symbol)

  ```
  examples = [(1,0,+), (4,0,-), (1,1,+), (3,1,-), (4,1,-), (1,2,+), (4,1,-), (1,3,+)]
  ```

## My work:

#### Technique 1:

```
examples = []
    for a in matrix:
        for b in a:
            if(matrix[a][b] == '+' || matrix[a][b] == '-' ):
                examples.append()
```

#### Technique 2:(*Making the use of enumerate()*)

```
list(enumerate(matrix[num]) for num in matrix)
```

The 2nd technique gives the following error though -

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but here is my code:

```
matrix = [['.', '+', '.', '.', '-'], ['.', '+', '.', '-', '-'], ['.', '+', '.', '.', '-'], ['.', '+', '.', '.', '-']]

lst = []
for lineIdx, line in enumerate(matrix) :
    for colIdx, col in enumerate(line) :
        if matrix[lineIdx][colIdx] in ['+', '-'] :
            lst.append((lineIdx, colIdx, matrix[lineIdx][colIdx]))
print lst
```

and output:

```
[(0, 1, '+'), (0, 4, '-'), (1, 1, '+'), (1, 3, '-'), (1, 4, '-'), 
(2, 1, '+'), (2, 4, '-'), (3, 1, '+'), (3, 4, '-')]
```

In my list I saved first line index, then column index.

Comment: In the line `for lineIdx, line` are lineIdx and line the same values? My question is, are we giving different names i.e. 'lineIdx' and 'line' to the same value i.e. number of elements in list 'matrix'?

Comment: No, please have a look at the enumerate() function. Here is a small example: a = [10, 20, 30]; for idx, elem in enumerate(a) : print idx, elem. idx is the list index zero-based, and elem is the actual list element. In our example lineIdx is the zero-based index of the list (i.e. the line index) and line is a list (i.e. a raw).

Answer (score 3):

```
In [7]: [ (i,j,character) for i, character in enumerate(row) for j, row in enumerate(matrix)  if character == '+' or character == '-']
Out[7]:
[(1, 0, '+'),
 (1, 1, '+'),
 (1, 2, '+'),
 (1, 3, '+'),
 (4, 0, '-'),
 (4, 1, '-'),
 (4, 2, '-'),
 (4, 3, '-')]
```

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was confusing previously, please see the updated question. The expected output is a list of tuples -`examples = [(1,0,+), (4,0,-), (1,1,+), (3,1,-), (4,1,-), (1,2,+), (4,1,-), (1,3,+)]`

Comment: the order is important. Is the output in that order because `if character ==  '+'` appearing first, iterates through the lists finding & listing all instances of '+' first?

Answer (score 1):

In the second technique, `num` is not an integer, it is some element of x.

You can do it in a single line like this:

```
>>>inp = [['.', '+', '.', '.', '-'], ['.', '+', '.', '-', '-'], ['.', '+', '.', '.', '-'], ['.', '+', '.', '.', '-']]
>>>[ (y[0], x[0], y[1]) for x in (enumerate(inp)) for y in enumerate(x[1]) if y[1] !='.']

[(1, 0, '+'), (4, 0, '-'), (1, 1, '+'), (3, 1, '-'), (4, 1, '-'), (1, 2, '+'), (4, 2, '-'), (1, 3, '+'), (4, 3, '-')]
```